# I am working on Jaro wrinkler similarity, and I am able to use between 2 columns, but how do I use it with 2 pairs of columns

Tags: python, pandas, jaro-winkler

Example i have 4 column in my dataframe,
i want to use jaro similarity for col: A,B  vs col: C,D containing strings

Currently i am using it between 2 columns using

`df.apply(lambda x: textdistance.jaro(x[A], x[C]),axis = 1))`

Currently i was comparing with names

|A|C |result|
|--| --- | --- |
|Kevin| kenny |0.67|
|Danny |Danny|1|
|Aiofa |Avril|0.75|
I have records over 100K in my dataframe

COLUMN A -contains strings of person name

COLUMN B -contains strings of city

COLUMN C -contains strings of person name (to compare with)

COLUMN D -contains strings of city (to compare with)

Expected Output
|A|B|C|D |result|
|--|--|---| --- | --- |
|Kevin|London| kenny|Leeds |0.4|
|Danny |Dublin|Danny|dublin|1|
|Aiofa|Madrid |Avril|Male|0.65|

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the data sample as text, not as a picture. E.g. try `df.head().to_dict(orient='list')` and post in a block between triple backticks (```). Show both input *and* expected output. Also, show us what you have tried so far, and why your attempt isn't giving you the result that you expect. See: [Research Effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: It depends on the application, so for your purpose would it make sense to compare by concatenations strings in the column pairs?  Meaning: `df.apply(lambda x: textdistance.jaro(x['A']  + x['B'], x['C'] + x['D']),axis = 1))`

Comment: Hi DarrylG, Thank you so much that worked well , thats what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

df.apply(lambda x: textdistance.jaro(x['A']  + x['B'], x['C'] + x['D']),axis = 1))

thank you DarrylG

Comment: Make sure to use markdown code formatting!